# Can I put a timer on a .on('keyup' to cut down the number of updates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code working:

```
$wmdInput.on('keyup', function () {
    var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
    });
});
```

However it seems to slow down my entering of characters. Is there some way I could put a timeout on this so that all the data is saved but it just does not do it more than for example once every two seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use [lodash](http://lodash.com/) (which you should) just wrap the function in [_.debounce](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce):

```
$wmdInput.on('keyup', _.debounce(function () {
    var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
    });
}, 300));
```

This will cause the function to be called only when the user has stopped typing for 300 ms -- obviously you should tweak the `wait` to whatever works best for you.

IMO debouncing is more appropriate than throttling in this case.

Comment: I'm not us9ing lodash but possibly I could use the same code that they use. I hope someone or yourself can maybe suggest this as an answer.

Comment: This gives an error from jQuery when I use this. The error is: Uncaught TypeError: Object 500 has no method 'apply'

Comment: Try it after my edit, I had the closing parenthesis in the wrong place.  You can see it working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/magnafides/mc2Wj/
Also on a side note, lodash is immensely useful -- I can't imagine doing any semi-serious Javascript without it.

Answer (score 3):

Pure AngularJS approach

```
var promise;
$wmdInput.on('keyup', function () {
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
    promise = $timeout(function() {
        var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
        ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reactive Extensions for JavaScript](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)  might be an option for you to use. You can setup the keyup event as an event source and throttle the events. In fact the README has an example that seems similar to what you want...

```
var $input = $('#input'),
    $results = $('#results');

/* Only get the value from each key up */
var keyups = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
    .map(function (e) {
        return e.target.value;
    })
    .filter(function (text) {
        return text.length > 2;
    });

/* Now throttle/debounce the input for 500ms */
var throttled = keyups
     .throttle(500 /* ms */);

/* Now get only distinct values, so we eliminate 
   the arrows and other control characters */
var distinct = throttled
    .distinctUntilChanged();
```

In your case you may not want the `filter` for `length > 2`, so just remove that expression. Regardless, you can just tack on a `subscribe` at the end to process your event

```
distinct.subscribe(function(value) {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
    });
});
```

And there are [bindings for AngularJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js) for you as well.

Answer (score -2):

in the function above, add two lines to:

- remove keyup event from wmdInput.
- set timer to add keyup event to
  wmdInput after 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you give an example of this with the above code so it's easy to see what you mean. Thanks

Comment: That would re-bind it after 2 seconds but not actually trigger it. Hence if the user entered a new character during the 2 seconds but not after it was rebound the last character is lost. Maybe you could add a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) using the angularJs CDN to show how you would do it?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Losing the last character would certainly be a problem. Thanks for your comment