# How to update ng-model without focus and changing? angularjs

Tags: angularjs, textarea, wysiwyg, redactor

I'm using wysiwyg-redactor with textarea, and it has ng-model, but when I call Sumbit function, my ng-model is undefined. (When using redactor, it makes textarea display:none and show own div where I could write text, but at the same time, my textarea has text like "

some text

)
As I understand, ng-model will be undefined until I focus it and write something in textarea. Can I get my model without it?

UPDATE

At first, I create django form for Comment

```
class CommentForm(NgModelFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    article = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    text_comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'redactor':"{buttons: ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic']}"}), required=True,  label=u'Текст комментария')



    <div class="redactor_box">
<ul class="redactor_toolbar">
<li><a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Formatting" class="redactor_btn_formatting" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
<li class="redactor_separator"></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Bold" class="redactor_btn_bold" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Italic" class="redactor_btn_italic" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
</ul><div class="redactor_ng-pristine redactor_ng-valid redactor_editor" contenteditable="true" dir="ltr">
<p><br></p></div>
<textarea cols="40" id="id_text_comment" name="text_comment" ng-model="comment.text_comment" redactor="{buttons: ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic']}" rows="10" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" style="display: none;"></textarea>
</div>
```

And that's how it generate in html code with redactor, so my textarea is not allowed to user for input

Comment: Can you show some code? I'm not sure it's entirely clear what you're trying to do here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I put a timer on a .on('keyup' to cut down the number of updates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884126/can-i-put-a-timer-on-a-onkeyup-to-cut-down-the-number-of-updates)